# How get base64 string from the application/octet-stream using .net or javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, base64, filestream, octetstring

I have to read file(pdf) from server and web service response i am getting of type application/octet-stream 
I need to create file stream and create file(pdf).

Comment: What issue are you having with the code that you have tried to resolve Question?

Comment: I was able to make it working. by using
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";